# Is it possible to save hexadecimal code of image files in RAM via clipboard?

Tags: windows, cmd, clipboard

This is my first question, and I am aware that it may sound strange:

We all know that the access to RAM memory is faster than access to hard disk. I wonder if it is possible to make a program able to:

1) Open a .CBZ/.CBR comic file and decompress it entirely in RAM

2) Read the images stored in RAM one by one, selecting whichever you want

Or, to simplify things:

1) Decompress a .CBZ/.CBR comic on disk, and

2) Use a Windows command line like this:

```
type image.jpg | clip
```

in order to store the hexadecimal code in clipboard, and later, be able to read it and interpret it as JPG with a program (and of course, show it in screen).

I know that when you use "type file.ext | clip" on a console window with a non-plain text file, the content is not accurately saved in the clipboard. Is there a trick to convert it to hex before dumping to clipboard?

And first of all: does my idea even makes sense?

Comment: What you're suggesting doesn't make a lot of sense. You can only store one thing in the clipboard a time. Why go through the indirection of using the clipboard, one image a time, when a CBZ/CBR viewer can just read the CBZ/CBR directly?

Comment: Or, to simplify your second option, 1) decompress the comic on disk, and 2) load the image.jpg into your program for display when you need it.

Comment: sadly `clip` only takes text. If speed is really an issue, consider using a RAM-Disk.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and corrections. My main idea was finding an easy -or at least, plausible- way to (temporary) have a lot of images on RAM, and of course, work with them (read and show). The viewing speed of comic viewers like STDU and Sumatra PDF led me to the conclusion that they decompress .CBZ/.CBR files directly to RAM, so that's why I asked about those possibilities.